# Chrome extension: passing variables to a popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an etension for Google Chrome. I am monitoring page text selection and i want the popup page to recieve the selected text when i click on the popup button.

Is there a way to pass variables to a popup? I understand, that messging doen't work for closed popups, so what should i do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once a text is selected send it to a background page where you would store it in lets say `textSelection` global variable. Once popup is opened you can access this variable with:

```
var selection = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().textSelection;
```

(you can access any variable and function from a background page directly, without requests)

Answer (score 0):

Your question can't be concisely answered, but I recommend you look here and read through some of the code samples:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html