# Communicating with a content script on active tab from a Chrome extension's page action popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm not getting how to pass data between content script and page action popup.

I've started with the following simple skeleton, that shows an page action for any page having a minus-dash in title:

- Extension manifest (`manifest.json`):

  ```
  {
     …
     "permissions": ["http://example.org/*"],
     "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
     "page_action": {"default_popup": "popup.html", …},
     "content_scripts": {
       "matches": ["http://example.org/*"],
       "js": ["content.js"]
     }
  }
  ```
- Background script (`background.js`):

  ```
  chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (msg, sender, respond) {
    if (msg && msg.what === "match") {
      console.log("Match:", msg.title);
      chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    }
  }
  ```
- Content script (`content.js`), checking document titles:

  ```
  var title = document.title;
  if (title.indexOf("-") >= 0) {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({"what": "match", "title": title});
  }
  ```

Now, in a page action's popup, I want to show matched page's title. Not the last loaded page's title (as would be done by using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7217280/116546)), but the title of the active tab.

My first though was to send a query to the content script, but according to documentation `chrome.extension.sendMessage` will send it to *all* listeners (i.e. all my content scripts on all tabs), without any clear definition on whose response I'll receive back. Also, I can't use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` as it *requires* `tabId`. Trying to find the current tab using `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` will return `null`, as the query comes from non-tab context (from a popup).

I guess I could probably use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to communicate, but this just feels dirty.

Still, I believe, this is a basic thing that should be very simple to do and I'm just missing something. Could someone, please, help me, preferably, with an example code?

**Update:** I've found [Mappy example extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#4042eaccda909714a2b78cfe60d59b9f) and it uses `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` to keep track of the active tab. This, unfortunately, requires `tabs` permission. Personally, I'd like to use least privileges possible.

So, is it just unfortunately bad permission system design and I have no choice but to do it this way, or there's any workaround? I'd be happy if `chrome.pageAction.onClicked` event handler (which provides `Tab` object that I need) would allow me to show a popup...

Comment: Did you try calling the content.js script from the popup.html?

Comment: @im_benton, I doubt this is possible. Content scripts are running in another context, separate from popup. As I understand things, they don't share anything except for the `chrome.extension` message bus.

Anyway, out of curiousity, I've tried declaring a function in `content.js` then calling it from `popup.js` (a script referenced from `popup.html`) and it obviously failed.

Comment: "This, unfortunately, requires `tabs` permission. Personally, I'd like to use least privileges possible." This is precisely what the `activeTab` permission is for: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the `onClick` event listener in your popup:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tabs.Tab tab) {...});
```

See documentation [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#event-onClicked).

Callback of the event listener would provide you the tabId which would surely be the active tab.

Comment: How does this onclick listener help OP, where he has `page_action": {"default_popup": "popup.html"` in his manifest.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple Problems in your code

- **chrome.extension.sendRequest** in `chrome.extension.sendRequest({"what": "match", "title": title});` is deprecated
- **chrome.pageAction.onClicked** will not fire when  you have `"page_action": {"default_popup": "popup.html", …},` in your manifest.
- `chrome.extension.sendMessage will send it to all listeners (i.e. all my content scripts on all tabs),` is an invalid assumption, it will send to Extension Pages.

I tried to read your question multiple times but couldn't understand what is you want to achieve, could you explain it?

Comment: What I want:

1. Content script performs a check on document and on positive match, a page action icon is displayed. In my example, it's checking document title for "-" presence.
2. User may open multiple tabs and switch them in any order.
3. When user clicks on a page action icon, a popup opens, that contains some information about the document in current tab (i.e. the tab, page action belongs), as exracted by content script. I've asked about a document title, but an ideal example would be displaying the text of a page's first `<h1>`.

Comment: @drdaeman If you need just title of page no need of content script, tabs api can provide you this information, check [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab), this is all achievable with `message passing`, `content scripts` and `background page`, now where are you struck?

Comment: I'm stuck trying to pass a message from a popup page to a content script running in active tab.

Comment: @drdaeman: Can you post code of message passing, i will try identifying problem.